# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on selector in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've got a UIBarButtonItem category where I build UIBarButtonItems with custom UIButtons, since I've found UIButtons easier to customize then UIBarButtonItems.

Now, I'd like to continue to use the BarButtonItem's target and action properties instead of using those in the button so that the BarButtonItem can continue to be customized externally without anyone having to know the implementation details (i.e., that it is using  a button internally).

Now, in order to do that, I'm written up this code in my category:

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItemWithColor:(UIColor *)color 
{
    UIImage *closeIcon = [MyImageUtility navBarBackArrow];
    if (color) closeIcon = [closeIcon imageWithColorOverlay:color];

    UIButton *close = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, closeIcon.size.width+10.0f, closeIcon.size.height+10.0f)];
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:close];
    [close setImage:closeIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [close addTarget:item action:@selector(SD_executeBarButtonItemAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return item;
}


- (void)SD_executeBarButtonItemAction
{
    [self.target performSelector:self.action];
}
```

Whenever the SD_executeBarButtonItemAction is called, I get a exc_bad_access on the selector, though I am not sure why. Any ideas? Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

here is the code being called by that selector that is crashing:

```
void (^transition)(void) = ^(void) {
    [self.rightContainer  setFrame:[self offscreenContainerFrame]];
    [self.centerContainer setAlpha:1.0f]; //TODO: this is unreliable in iOS6 -- we should add a view to the top of it to darken
    [self.centerContainer setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
};

[self notifyWillShowPrimaryViewController];

[self performBlock:transition animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self notifyDidShowPrimaryViewController];
    [self setForegroundController:self.primaryNavigationController];
    if (block != NULL) block(finished);
}];
```

Comment: what is `self.action` ?

Comment: Where do you set the target and action of the `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: it is the action property of UIBarButtonItem

Comment: They are set like [back setTarget:self]; and [back setAction:@selector(showPrimaryAction:)]; where self is a viewController

Comment: Is it possible the bar button's target has been deallocated by the time the bar button is tapped?

Comment: No, the target is the rootViewController of the application, its definitely sticking around...

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser: i think it's a recursive call, you are setting `UIBarButtonItem`  as your target

Comment: Seems really odd to add this as a category on the `UI*Button*` class.   Bad code smell, that.  Why can't you use the normal target/action mechanism?

Comment: this is a category on UIBarButtonItem. I just want to call the target/action of the BarButtonItem instead of setting those properties on the UIButton.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a recursive call.

```
- (void)SD_executeBarButtonItemAction
{
    [self.target performSelector:self.action];
}
```

You set like:

```
[close addTarget:item action:@selector(SD_executeBarButtonItemAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Where `item` is a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: don't think it is recursive -- the UIButton (close) invokes the selector on the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser: I don't think that's what happening, please put a break point and check whether both target and action is correct

Comment: (lldb) po [self class]
UIBarButtonItem
(lldb) po self.target
<MLPhoneRootContainerViewController: 0xac95160>
(lldb) po NSStringFromSelector(self.action)
showPrimaryAction:  -- looks right to me. The UIBarButtonItem is invoking the showPrimaryAction: selector on the controller, which is conceptually what I want to happen. I must be missing something obvious ...

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser: Is that method implemented in the `MLPhoneRootContainerViewController` ? Can you paste the method declaration ?

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser: I think I got the issue, but need to verify it is correct or not. I think it is the issue with your selector method (showPrimaryAction:) implementation

Comment: ahh i believe u are correct that it has something to do with the method itself. I commented out everything and replaced it with a log statement, and it no longer crashes. Code executed it added to the question above